# How to use the determiner THE

Tags: determiners

I need to hand my pupils a list of adverbs about feelings.
Should I entitle it: "Adverbs to express intensity of feelings" or "Adverbs to express THE intensity of feelings"?

Comment: They're probably both fine... what are some examples of the adverbs on the list? That could conceivably help, but probably not.  I think they're the same.

Comment: Adverbs to modify adjectives of feelings or emotions such as: not very ; not so; a bit / a little  < quite ; pretty; so < very ; really ; extremely

Comment: Oh, ok.  As I suspected, both are fine.  I notice, though, that these terms are used to express the intensity of almost any adjective, not just feelings.  So you could also say: "Adverbs to express intensity."  In that formulation, you wouldn't use "the."